# Opening up a program with arguments gets file not found

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am coding a program which uses another program to decrypt a file. I use a `combobox` for the selected item and then use this to decrypt it:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim strpath As String = Application.StartupPath
        Process.Start(strpath & "\pdatool.exe", "-g NPUB30943 -d " & FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath & " " & ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
End sub
```

When I try to do this. I get that `ComboBox1.SelectedItem` is not found in the `FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath`.

What am I doing wrong? I appreciate all help that I receive thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use a debugger and describe what `FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath` and `ComboBox1.SelectedItem` evaluate to.

Comment: Try to ComboBox1.SelectedText